# Some layouts expanding slower than others when using LayoutTransition.CHANGING

Tags: android

I have 19 horizontal linearlayouts that are arranged vertically within another linearlayout. They are nearly empty and onclick show text. I am animating the layouts with

```
parentOne.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
```

For some reason the first 7 layouts seem to be opening onClick a little slower than the 8th. Only by a split second but I have asked others to look at it when I open it to make sure I'm not crazy. I would post the entire file but it is HUGE and is over the maximum allowable text on this. So here is the meat and potatoes. So, why are my layouts opening slower than others? Numbers 8-19 open instantly onClick and 1-7 have a small delay that is noticeable.

Java On Create

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.tacticalfieldcarestudy);

    LinearLayout parentOne = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutOne);
    LinearLayout parentTwo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutTwo);
    LinearLayout parentTwoBullets = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutTwoBullets);
    LinearLayout parentThree = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutThree);
    LinearLayout parentThreeBullets = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutThreeBullets);
    LinearLayout parentFour = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutFour);
    LinearLayout parentFourBullets = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutFourBullets);
    LinearLayout parentFive = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutFive);
    LinearLayout parentFiveBullets = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutFiveBullets);
    LinearLayout parentSix = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutSix);
    LinearLayout parentSixBullets = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutSixBullets);
    LinearLayout parentSeven = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutSeven);
    LinearLayout parentSevenBullets = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutSevenBullets);
    LinearLayout parentEight = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutEight);
    LinearLayout parentEightBullets = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutEightBullets);
    LinearLayout parentNine = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutNine);
    LinearLayout parentNineBullets = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutNineBullets);
    LinearLayout parentTen = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutTen);
    LinearLayout parentTenBullets = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutTenBullets);
    LinearLayout parentEleven = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutEleven);
    LinearLayout parentTwelve = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutTwelve);
    LinearLayout parentThirteen = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutThirteen);
    LinearLayout parentThirteenBullets = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutThirteenBullets);
    LinearLayout parentFourteen = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutFourteen);
    LinearLayout parentFifteen = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutFifteen);
    LinearLayout parentFifteenBullets = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutFifteenBullets);
    LinearLayout parentSixteen = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutSixteen);
    LinearLayout parentSixteenBullets = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutSixteenBullets);
    LinearLayout parentSeventeen = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutSeventeen);
    LinearLayout parentSeventeenBullets = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutSeventeenBullets);
    LinearLayout parentEighteen = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutEighteen);
    LinearLayout parentEighteenBullets = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutEighteenBullets);
    LinearLayout parentNineteen = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutNineteen);
    LinearLayout parentNineteenBullets = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutNineteenBullets);

    parentOne.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentTwo.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentTwoBullets.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentThree.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentThreeBullets.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentFour.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentFourBullets.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentFive.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentFiveBullets.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentSix.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentSixBullets.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentSeven.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentSevenBullets.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentEight.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentEightBullets.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentNine.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentNineBullets.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentTen.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentTenBullets.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentEleven.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentTwelve.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentThirteen.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentThirteenBullets.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentFourteen.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentFifteen.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentFifteenBullets.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentSixteen.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentSixteenBullets.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentSeventeen.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentSeventeenBullets.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentEighteen.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentEighteenBullets.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentNineteen.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    parentNineteenBullets.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
}
```

One of 7 Java methods that has unwanted delay onClick

```
private boolean mOpenOne = false;

public void toggleOne(View view){
    TextView stepOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stepOne);
    ImageView toggle = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.toggleStepOne);

    if(mOpenOne){
        stepOne.setText("Step 1:");
        toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.open);
    }
    else{
        stepOne.setText("1. Casualties with an altered mental status should be disarmed immediately.");
        toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.close);
    }
    mOpenOne = !mOpenOne;
}
```

XML with unwanted delay onClick

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TFCLayoutOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:onClick="toggleOne"
        android:background="#606060"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toggleStepOne"
            android:src="@drawable/open"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stepOne"
            android:text="Step 1:"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            style="@style/Bullet"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Java for 8th method that works without delay

```
private boolean mOpenEight = false;

public void toggleEight(View view){
    TextView stepEight = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stepEight);
    ImageView toggle = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.toggleStepEight);

    if(mOpenEight){
        stepEight.setText("Step 8:");
        TextView stepEightBulletOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stepEightBulletOne);
        TextView stepEightBulletTwo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stepEightBulletTwo);
        TextView stepEightBulletThree = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stepEightBulletThree);
        TextView stepEightBulletFour = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stepEightBulletFour);
        TextView stepEightBulletFive = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stepEightBulletFive);
        TextView stepEightBulletSix = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stepEightBulletSix);
        stepEightBulletOne.setText("");
        stepEightBulletTwo.setText("");
        stepEightBulletThree.setText("");
        stepEightBulletFour.setText("");
        stepEightBulletFive.setText("");
        stepEightBulletSix.setText("");
        stepEightBulletOne.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        stepEightBulletTwo.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        stepEightBulletThree.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        stepEightBulletFour.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        stepEightBulletFive.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        stepEightBulletSix.getLayoutParams().height = 0;

        toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.open);
    }
    else{
        stepEight.setText("8. Prevention of hypothermia");
        TextView stepEightBulletOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stepEightBulletOne);
        TextView stepEightBulletTwo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stepEightBulletTwo);
        TextView stepEightBulletThree = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stepEightBulletThree);
        TextView stepEightBulletFour = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stepEightBulletFour);
        TextView stepEightBulletFive = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stepEightBulletFive);
        TextView stepEightBulletSix = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stepEightBulletSix);
        stepEightBulletOne.setText("a. Minimize casualty's exposure to the elements. Keep protective gear on or with the casualty if feasible.");
        stepEightBulletTwo.setText("b. Replace wet clothing with dry if possible. Get the casualty onto an insulated surface as soon as possible.");
        stepEightBulletThree.setText("c. Apply the Ready-Heat Blanket from the Hypothermia Prevention and Management Kit (HPMK) to the casualty's torso (not directly on the skin) and cover the casualty with the Heat-Reflective Shell (HRS).");
        stepEightBulletFour.setText("d. If an HRS is not available, the previously recommended combination of the Blizzard Survival Blanket and the Ready Heat blanket may also be used.");
        stepEightBulletFive.setText("e. If the items mentioned above are not available, use dry blankets, poncho liners, sleeping bags, or anything that will retain heat and keep the casualty dry.");
        stepEightBulletSix.setText("f. Warm fluids are preferred if IV fluids are required.");
        stepEightBulletOne.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        stepEightBulletTwo.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        stepEightBulletThree.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        stepEightBulletFour.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        stepEightBulletFive.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        stepEightBulletSix.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.close);
    }
    mOpenEight = !mOpenEight;
}
```

XML of one of the layouts that works without a delay

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/TFCLayoutEightBullets"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#A0A0A0"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:onClick="toggleEight"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TFCLayoutEight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="#A0A0A0"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toggleStepEight"
            android:src="@drawable/open"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stepEight"
            android:text="Step 8:"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            style="@style/Bullet"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stepEightBulletOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        style="@style/BulletIndented"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stepEightBulletTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        style="@style/BulletIndented"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stepEightBulletThree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        style="@style/BulletIndented"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stepEightBulletFour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        style="@style/BulletIndented"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stepEightBulletFive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        style="@style/BulletIndented"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stepEightBulletSix"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        style="@style/BulletIndented"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out. It looks as though it was a processing issue. If I had to guess I would say that each time I called a method it would search through the giant list of linearlayouts in the onCreate method for the animation to open it.

In my onCreate method I define a CRAP TON of linear layouts as such

```
LinearLayout parentOne = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutOne);
parentOne.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
```

The Fix:

I separated ALL of them and placed them all in their respective onClick methods. Now, when I click them they actually open faster than my other pages that are setup similarly, so I will be changing those as well. My java methods were:

```
private boolean mOpenOne = false;

public void toggleOne(View view){
TextView stepOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stepOne);
ImageView toggle = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.toggleStepOne);

if(mOpenOne){
    stepOne.setText("Step 1:");
    toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.open);
}
else{
    stepOne.setText("1. Casualties with an altered mental status should be disarmed immediately.");
    toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.close);
}
mOpenOne = !mOpenOne;
```

}

I have changed them to:

```
private boolean mOpenOne = false;

public void toggleOne(View view){
    TextView stepOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stepOne);
    ImageView toggle = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.toggleStepOne);
    LinearLayout parentOne = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.TFCLayoutOne);
    parentOne.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);

    if(mOpenOne){
        stepOne.setText("Step 1:");
        toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.open);
    }
    else{
        stepOne.setText("1. Casualties with an altered mental status should be disarmed immediately.");
        toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.close);
    }
    mOpenOne = !mOpenOne;
}
```

Hope this helps others!